# From where i can get AuthenticationFault Exception jar?

Tags: authentication

Hi I am authenticating `alfresco` using `WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress` but i am getting following error:

```
 No exception of type AuthenticationFault can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem, please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the `org.alfresco.webservice.authentication` package within the [alfresco-web-service-client-3.2.jar](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Labs_3_Final_download_files#Alfresco_Web_Service_Client).

As to why your authentication is failing, make sure you put the `webserviceclient.properties` file in the alfresco folder. Alfresco reads this property `repository.location=http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api`.

Check their SDK for more elaborated sample codes.